# Segmentation of a static object in a video

Tags: computer-vision, image-segmentation

I've videos from a mounted camera on a helmet and the manually segmented labels (mask) of them.

The mask is valid through the entire video, only the scene vary. 
In different videos the camera is mounted differently on top of the helmet.

Things I've tried:

- Training semantic segmentation on frame-mask pairs
- Training semantic segmentation of concatenated frames with the mask.
- Averaging consecutive frames and calculating the time-wise std of the pixels, and feeding the NN with this as an input.
- ensembling (averaging) segmentation results from N frames
- Usage of classic background subtraction techniques such as MOG2 (worse)

Although DNN models achieve 99% accuracy during training, in some of my test videos the model is missing large part of the helmet..

I'm certain this task can achieve ~100% accuracy even for never-before-seen examples.

Do you have some ideas?